# Changing default compiler option of a Solution

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2015

I have a few Projects under a Solution and I am writing code in C. Whenever I make a new project under this Solution, I should change the compiler from "default" to "Compile as C Code (/TC)" by right clicking the project and going into Configuration Properties - C/C++ - All Options - Compile As. Instead of this, is there a way to set the compiler of a Solution once and this would apply to all the projects under that solution instead of changing every one of them one by one?

Comment: No, because the compiler is operative at the project level, not the solution level. Choosing `C` for a solution that also contains a VB project would make no sense.

Comment: Anyway, MSVC respect the source file extension and compiles as C any *.c file

Comment: @MarkBenningfield: The compiler operates at the compilation unit level. You can have a project, where compilation units are compiled as C and C++ code. Anyway, the compiler does the right thing in compiling .c files as C, unless instructed not to.

Comment: Is it so? I created a simple code and named as .c file. When I compiled it hanged. (default) Then I changed Compile as option to  "Compile as C Code (/TC)" and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/SyS6kuaOM    try this with Visual Studio 2015. When you leave the compiler as default, program hangs.

Comment: @IInspectable: You misunderstand. If I restate to say the exact same thing as "The compiler is not operative at the solution level, but at the project level", does that make it clearer? That doesn't mean that you can only have one compiler per project; it means that you can't have _any_ compilers per solution.

Comment: @Lyrk: Compiled and executed code at your link on VS2015. Renamed `stdafx.cpp` to `stdafx.c` and `ConsoleApplication1.cpp` to `ConsoleApplication1`.c`. `CompileAs` setting is "Default". No problems.

Comment: I do not understand. Maybe my Visual Studio Installation is faulty. Thanks for trying. I will reinstall then.